# Long Image links of Facebook is not working in Flex4 mx.image.souce

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flexbuilder

I am creating one desktop application of facebook.

So here I am getting streams from facebook post.
So when any facebook application's long image link I am getting that I can't display in Image container, this is not displaying image.

One also fact is that, When I am giving this link directly then it is working.....

I am full confused what is going on.
When I have seen this in Charlse Debugging proxy then it is displaying 403,Forbidden error of image.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Does the facebook server serving the images have a crossdomain.xml file?  If not, you won't be able to load those image URLs in Flex.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be a crossdomain.xml file for the FB server or from where you are loading that image. You can use a proxy server side script in PHP/Python to get around this.